# JQuery - Drawing rectangle on image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to draw a red rectangle on image but somehow my rectangle is NOT starting from coordinates where I click with my mouse. Here is the code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let img = new Image();
let fileName = "";

let rect = {};
let drag = false;
  // Add image to canvas
reader.addEventListener(
    "load",
    () => {
      // Create image
      img = new Image();
      // Set image src
      img.src = reader.result;
      // On image load add to canvas
      img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        canvas.removeAttribute("data-caman-id");
      };
      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    },
    false
  );
});


function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { drag = false; }

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        console.log("rect.startX: " + rect.startX + " - rect.startY: " +rect.startY)
    }
}
```

And here is what I get in return:

[image]

I cannot show my mouse position when I take screenshot so I've labeled it on the image. Basically, I start from top left corner and rectangle seems to start drawing itself from bottom right corner. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK my answer is more related to the (original) question title and a little bit of jQuery fun.

Your (original) question code involves `canvas` and no `jQuery` code, just javascript.

This answer is more just a primitive `jQuery` approach.

Here is a very rough concept below using `jQuery` `.on` events for handling...

- `mousedown` event to start drawing the rectangle
- `resize` event for updating image size and offsets
- `mousemove` event for updating rectangle draw positions
- `mouseup` event for setting rectangle in set position

All of the above `.on` events (excluding `resize` event) run in document selector `.area`, which has a child `img` element in this example below.

> Please note I have not coded this example for multiple usages of `.area` div, you will need go even deeper with the script logic in my example to accommodate multiple usages of `.area` div.

My script example code below may inspire you to get to where you want, may not.

**The main key thing I am doing is converting pixel cursor positions within the image into a percentage integer. Using percentages as `xy` positions means the rendered result will be the same if the `window` or `.area` is resized responsively (with no javascript).**

Here is a `jQuery` and `CSS` fun example below.

jsFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/w5bcx9o8/2/

See comments in code to understand what is happening...

```js
// our updatable variable objects to use globally
let img = {};
let position = {};

// image matrix function to update img object variable
function imgMatrix() {

  // our image object inside area
  let $img = $('IMG', '.area');

  // offset data of image
  let offset = $img.offset();

  // add/update object key data
  img.width = $img.outerWidth();
  img.height = $img.outerHeight();
  img.offsetX = offset.left - $(document).scrollLeft();
  img.offsetY = offset.top - $(document).scrollTop();

}

// position matrix function to update position object variable
function positionMatrix(e, mousedown = false) {

  // if mousedown param is true... for use in 
  if (mousedown) {

    // set the top/left position object data with percentage position
    position.top = (100 / img.height) * ( (e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop()) - img.offsetY);
    position.left = (100 / img.width) * ( (e.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft()) - img.offsetX);

  }

  // set the right/bottom position object data with percentage position
  position.right = 100 - ((100 / img.width) * ((e.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft()) - img.offsetX));
  position.bottom = 100 - ((100 / img.height) * ((e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop()) - img.offsetY));

}

// mouse move event function in area div
$(document).on('mousemove', '.area', function(e) {

  // update img object variable data upon this mousemove event
  imgMatrix();

  // if this area has draw class
  if ($(this).hasClass('draw')) {

    // update position object variable data passing current event data
    positionMatrix(e);

    // if image x cursor drag position percent is negative to mousedown x position
    if ((100 - position.bottom) < position.top) {

      // update rectange x negative positions css
      $('.rect', this).css({
        top: (100 - position.bottom) + '%',
        bottom: (100 - position.top) + '%'
      });

    // else if image x cursor drag position percent is positive to mousedown x position
    } else {

      // update rectange x positive positions css
      $('.rect', this).css({
        bottom: position.bottom + '%',
        top: position.top + '%',
      });

    }

    // if image y cursor drag position percent is negative to mousedown y position
    if ((100 - position.right) < position.left) {

      // update rectange y negative positions css
      $('.rect', this).css({
        left: (100 - position.right) + '%',
        right: (100 - position.left) + '%'
      });

    // else if image y cursor drag position percent is positive to mousedown y position
    } else {

      // update rectange y positive positions css
      $('.rect', this).css({
        right: position.right + '%',
        left: position.left + '%'
      });

    }

  }

});

// mouse down event function in area div
$(document).on('mousedown', '.area', function(e) {

  // remove the drawn class
  $(this).removeClass('drawn');

  // update img object variable data upon this mousedown event
  imgMatrix();

  // update position object variable data passing current event data and mousedown param as true 
  positionMatrix(e, true);

  // update rectange xy positions css
  $('.rect', this).css({
    left: position.left + '%',
    top: position.top + '%',
    right: position.right + '%',
    bottom: position.bottom + '%'
  });

  // add draw class to area div to reveal rectangle
  $(this).addClass('draw');

});

// mouse up event function in area div
$(document).on('mouseup', '.area', function(e) {

  // update img object variable data upon this mouseup event
  imgMatrix();

  // if this area had draw class
  if ($(this).hasClass('draw')) {

    // update position object variable data passing current event
    positionMatrix(e);

    // math trunc on position values if x and y values are equal, basically no drawn rectangle on mouseup event
    if ((Math.trunc(position.left) === Math.trunc(100 - position.right)) && (Math.trunc(position.top) === Math.trunc(100 - position.bottom))) {
      
      // remove draw and drawn classes
      $(this).removeClass('draw drawn');

    // else if x and y values are not equal, basically a rectange has been drawn
    } else {

      // add drawn class and remove draw class
      $(this).addClass('drawn').removeClass('draw');

    }

  }

});

// on window resize function
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  
  // update img object variable data upon this window resize event
  imgMatrix();

});
```

```css
/* area div */
.area {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

/* area div hover cursor */
.area:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

/* img tag in area div */
.area IMG {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* rectangle div in area div */
.area .rect {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0s ease;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* rectangle div css when in draw or drawn mode */
.area.draw .rect,
.area.drawn .rect {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* below css is for fun rendering outer exclusion area of drawn rectangle div with a opaque overlay */

/* rectange exclusing pseudo elems base css */
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-x::before,
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-x::after,
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-y::before,
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-y::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .75;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* rectange outer opaque x above css */
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-x::before {
  bottom: calc(100% + 1px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 200vh;
  width: 200vw;
}

/* rectange outer opaque x below css */
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-x::after {
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 200vh;
  width: 200vw;
}

/* rectange outer opaque y left css */
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-y::before {
  right: calc(100% + 1px);
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 200vw;
}

/* rectange outer opaque y right css */
.area.drawn .rect .exclusion-y::after {
  left: calc(100% + 1px);
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 200vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <img src="https://dragonballsuper-france.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/DIHQF2OXoAAJi4n-660x330.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="rect">
    <div class="exclusion-x"></div>
    <div class="exclusion-y"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```